# extract Zipkin data

Tags: python, zipkin

I am currently using zipkin and I am trying to build a python script to extract the data saved and process them differently.

zipkin logs and UI are working fine.

I have done this :

```
   start = 1505754933996
   end = 1505758533996
   url = "http://zipkin.iamplus.xyz/?serviceName=" + service + "&spanName=all&startTs=" + str(start) + "&endTs=" + str(end) + "&minDuration=&limit=&annotationQuery=&sortOrder=duration-desc"
   print(url)
   #response = wget.download(url)
   response = requests.get(url)
```

I have used wget and request and both are giving me the result below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Webpack App</title>
  <link href="/app-0993bcc28157df364901.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app-0993bcc28157df364901.min.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

but If I copy paste the URL used in the request or wget in a web browser the result is shown

any idea how to extract the data in JSON or any other format for a Zipkin server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Zipkin UI is making an AJAX request to the API in order to retrieve the data that is displayed. You can find the API definition for zipkin at:

https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin-api

I believe you are looking for the URL: http://zipkin.iamplus.xyz/api/v1/traces

From there you will get the traces matching your filter